# How can I solve this problem loading Grakn schema and data at localhost:48555?

Tags: vaticle-typedb, vaticle-typeql, knowledge-graph

I'm using grakn core 1.8.4 with Windows 10. The grakn server and grakn storage are starting up normally, but when trying to load a schema, Grakn returns the following error message:

```
Unable to create connection to Grakn instance at localhost:48555
Cause: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException
UNKNOWN: ID block allocation on partition(30)-namespace(0) timed out in 2.000 min. Please check server logs for the stack trace.
```

I already checked and there are no other processes listening to the same port. I also disabled the Firewall and that did not solve the problem. Does anyone have any indication of how I should proceed?

Below is part of the log:

```
2021-01-05 14:19:24,387 [JanusGraphID(30)(0)[0]] WARN  g.c.g.d.i.ConsistentKeyIDAuthority - Temporary storage exception while acquiring id block - retrying in PT0.32S: {}
grakn.core.graph.diskstorage.TemporaryBackendException: Wrote claim for id block [1, 10001) in PT0.016S => too slow, threshold is: PT0.01S
    at grakn.core.graph.diskstorage.idmanagement.ConsistentKeyIDAuthority.getIDBlock(ConsistentKeyIDAuthority.java:320)
    at grakn.core.graph.graphdb.database.idassigner.StandardIDPool$IDBlockGetter.call(StandardIDPool.java:262)
    at grakn.core.graph.graphdb.database.idassigner.StandardIDPool$IDBlockGetter.call(StandardIDPool.java:232)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
2021-01-05 14:19:24,688 [grpc-request-handler-1] ERROR grakn.core.server.rpc.SessionService - An error has occurred
grakn.core.graph.core.JanusGraphException: ID block allocation on partition(30)-namespace(0) timed out in 2.000 min
    at grakn.core.graph.graphdb.database.idassigner.StandardIDPool.waitForIDBlockGetter(StandardIDPool.java:146)
    at grakn.core.graph.graphdb.database.idassigner.StandardIDPool.nextBlock(StandardIDPool.java:165)
    at grakn.core.graph.graphdb.database.idassigner.StandardIDPool.nextID(StandardIDPool.java:185)
    at grakn.core.graph.graphdb.database.idassigner.VertexIDAssigner.assignID(VertexIDAssigner.java:334)
    at grakn.core.graph.graphdb.database.idassigner.VertexIDAssigner.assignID(VertexIDAssigner.java:184)
    at grakn.core.graph.graphdb.database.idassigner.VertexIDAssigner.assignID(VertexIDAssigner.java:154)
    at grakn.core.graph.graphdb.database.StandardJanusGraph.assignID(StandardJanusGraph.java:416)
    at grakn.core.graph.graphdb.transaction.StandardJanusGraphTx.addVertex(StandardJanusGraphTx.java:636)
    at grakn.core.graph.graphdb.transaction.StandardJanusGraphTx.addVertex(StandardJanusGraphTx.java:653)
    at grakn.core.graph.graphdb.transaction.StandardJanusGraphTx.addVertex(StandardJanusGraphTx.java:649)
    at grakn.core.concept.structure.ElementFactory.addVertexElement(ElementFactory.java:104)
    at grakn.core.concept.manager.ConceptManagerImpl.addTypeVertex(ConceptManagerImpl.java:188)
    at grakn.core.server.session.TransactionImpl.createMetaConcepts(TransactionImpl.java:1297)
    at grakn.core.server.session.SessionImpl.initialiseMetaConcepts(SessionImpl.java:123)
    at grakn.core.server.session.SessionImpl.<init>(SessionImpl.java:85)
    at grakn.core.server.session.SessionFactory.session(SessionFactory.java:115)
    at grakn.core.server.rpc.ServerOpenRequest.open(ServerOpenRequest.java:40)
    at grakn.core.server.rpc.SessionService.open(SessionService.java:122)
    at grakn.protocol.session.SessionServiceGrpc$MethodHandlers.invoke(SessionServiceGrpc.java:339)
    at io.grpc.stub.ServerCalls$UnaryServerCallHandler$UnaryServerCallListener.onHalfClose(ServerCalls.java:172)
    at io.grpc.internal.ServerCallImpl$ServerStreamListenerImpl.halfClosed(ServerCallImpl.java:331)
    at io.grpc.internal.ServerImpl$JumpToApplicationThreadServerStreamListener$1HalfClosed.runInContext(ServerImpl.java:814)
    at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37)
    at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:123)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: null
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at grakn.core.graph.graphdb.database.idassigner.StandardIDPool.waitForIDBlockGetter(StandardIDPool.java:126)
    ... 26 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0):

If you get this error, you can try to increase the wait time with the following two parameters in the `grakn.properties` file:

```
# The number of milliseconds that the JanusGraph id pool manager will wait before
# giving up on allocating a new block of ids
root.ids.renew-timeout=10

# The number of milliseconds the system waits for an ID block reservation to be acknowledged by the storage backend
ids.authority.wait-time=10
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by increasing the below parameters from 10 o 100 in the `.\grakn\server\conf\grakn.properties` configuration file.

Not sure if this affects performances.

```
# The number of milliseconds that the JanusGraph id pool manager will wait before
# giving up on allocating a new block of ids
root.ids.renew-timeout=100

# The number of milliseconds the system waits for an ID block reservation to be acknowledged by the storage backend
ids.authority.wait-time=100
```